# Issue with diagrams made using tikzcd

Tags: tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams

I have made the following diagrams using the `tikz-cd` environment:

1. `\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=25pt]\emph{Aut}(A)\arrow[rr,"\phi_h"]&&\emph{Aut (A')\\&G\arrow[ur,"\rho'"]\arrow[ul,"\rho"]\end{tikzcd}\]`
2. `\[\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=25pt]X\arrow[rr,"h"]\arrow[dr,"f"]&&Y\arrow[dl,"g"]\\&A\end{tikzcd}\]`

How can I make it so that the $\rho'$ in the first diagram and the $f$ go below the arrow? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: As always on this site, please provide a full but minimal exmaple others can copy and test as is. For sniplets like this we have to guess your code and our guess might be different than yours.

Comment: That said, try `"\rho"'` note the latter is `"` and a `'`

Comment: Additionally make sure your code compiles, there is a `}` missing. And `\emph` should never even be here. Use `\operatorname{Aut}` for a one-of or use `\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}` in the preamble to define it for reuse.

Comment: This checklist may assist you with the MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10137/245790

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `'` after `"..."` to move it to the other side if the arrow

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\DeclareMathOperator\Aut{Aut}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=25pt]
  \Aut(A)\arrow[rr,"\phi_h"]
  && \Aut (A')
    \\
    &G\arrow[ur,"\rho'"']\arrow[ul,"\rho"]
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=25pt]
  X\arrow[rr,"h"]\arrow[dr,"f"']
  &&
  Y\arrow[dl,"g"]
  \\
  &
  A
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]